# Firestore Database Rules for User

Tags: firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following a tutorial about firestore but I don't understand firestore rules very well. I'm trying to allow anyone to be able to create in the standard 
    users/uid/ 
path but only allow updates if the requester is trying to update 
    users/theirUserId/ 
I saw this in the documentation, but it didn't seem to work for me:

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id;
```

Can anyone explain the functionality of the above line and/or offer suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

Additionally, is there any way to specify rules for a specific piece of data within a document?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that your document doesn't contain a `author_id` field.

The Firebase documentation [Writing Conditions for Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) use this example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches the 'author_id' field
    // of the document
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id;
    }
  }
}
```

It means that a random user will be able to `read` and `write` in the `users` collections **only** if their authentication ID equals the `author_id` field of a specific document.

> The resource variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. For more information on the resource variable, see the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#firestore-resource).

For your second question, I recommend you to have a look on the documentation about `resource` variable (link in the quote above). It is the same logic as your `author_id` question.

Answer (score 0):

You can split `allow write` in to three `create`, `update`, `delete` for specific cases.

In your case

```
allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id;
```

which says any authenticated users can create and only update their on document. and created user must have a field `author_id` which is their user id.

Comment: This: ***request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id*** is not working. When I type resource then data, there is no option for author_id. Help is appreciated.

Comment: @RonTLV `data` refers to your current data node in firestore. there must a field `author_id` to reference it.